# how does wordpress store long blogs in its database?

Tags: html, wordpress, mongodb, blogs, database

I am trying to make a blog using nodejs and mongodb. I want to store all my blog contents in mongodb and load it from there. What would be the best way to do so?
I was wondering how wordpress stores the blog content and displays them in a proper formatted way.
Do I need to bisect the blog contents and then make a html structure out of the contents and save the entire thing in the database or is there any other way to keep the texts formatted and make html structure after fetching the contents?
Don't be hating for a noob question. :)

Comment: a simple what I am doing wrong with down vote would be appreciated. Don't be anonymous down voter just cause you can

Answer (score 1):

You can see how WordPress does this by looking at the [source of wp_update_post()](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3528). Essentially, it escapes all special characters, runs [wp_slash()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_slash), and saves the post data in a `longtext` database field.